# AES Decryption gives inconsistent results

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I have tried to decrypt a string I am given using code I found online, but it gives me a wrong answer.

On http://aesencryption.net/ , my string gets correctly decrypted in the online tool, if I just enter the string, key and 128-bit. However, upon running the java code on the same page, I get a different result, which has a lot of non-utf8 characters.

I am not the one encoding the string and all I know is the key, that the string is utf8, and I should use AES128, I saw many online resources using other values, but I have neither of those and the online tool works, regardless.

I would like to get this working in ASP, but getting the java to work would be a nice first step. As previously mentioned, all online code samples I found gave me gibberish characters, only this online tool has worked for me.

The string is "k8emKaWRSiTa9A0bPSsRoVysvx00EleLD+A8khtH8VVX2tDlI6/DVnLMYUdXWX9MZZKgPJohzpNN6s8bBzzDSzxDXuzx30w7NErpCiaw5zEKQ6Q5pYadG/KMsZ6KwVuRqfEfmKuFP9QWHZS4Bp36lw==" and the key is a 16 character string I have been given.

Edit: sample code I have tried, adapted from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C (I only changed the key size from 32 to 16 and the text encoding) :

```
   // Decrypt a string into a string using a password 
//    Uses Decrypt(byte[], byte[], byte[]) 

public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string Password) 
{ 
    // First we need to turn the input string into a byte array. 
    // We presume that Base64 encoding was used 
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText); 

    // Then, we need to turn the password into Key and IV 
    // We are using salt to make it harder to guess our key
    // using a dictionary attack - 
    // trying to guess a password by enumerating all possible words. 
    PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, 
        new byte[] {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 
        0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76}); 

    // Now get the key/IV and do the decryption using
    // the function that accepts byte arrays. 
    // Using PasswordDeriveBytes object we are first
    // getting 32 bytes for the Key 
    // (the default Rijndael key length is 256bit = 32bytes)
    // and then 16 bytes for the IV. 
    // IV should always be the block size, which is by
    // default 16 bytes (128 bit) for Rijndael. 
    // If you are using DES/TripleDES/RC2 the block size is
    // 8 bytes and so should be the IV size. 
    // You can also read KeySize/BlockSize properties off
    // the algorithm to find out the sizes. 
    byte[] decryptedData = Decrypt(cipherBytes, 
        pdb.GetBytes(16), pdb.GetBytes(16)); 

    // Now we need to turn the resulting byte array into a string. 
    // A common mistake would be to use an Encoding class for that.
    // It does not work 
    // because not all byte values can be represented by characters. 
    // We are going to be using Base64 encoding that is 
    // designed exactly for what we are trying to do. 
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData); 
}

   // Decrypt a byte array into a byte array using a key and an IV 
public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherData, 
                            byte[] Key, byte[] IV) 
{ 
    // Create a MemoryStream that is going to accept the
    // decrypted bytes 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 

    // Create a symmetric algorithm. 
    // We are going to use Rijndael because it is strong and
    // available on all platforms. 
    // You can use other algorithms, to do so substitute the next
    // line with something like 
    //     TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create(); 
    Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create(); 

    // Now set the key and the IV. 
    // We need the IV (Initialization Vector) because the algorithm
    // is operating in its default 
    // mode called CBC (Cipher Block Chaining). The IV is XORed with
    // the first block (8 byte) 
    // of the data after it is decrypted, and then each decrypted
    // block is XORed with the previous 
    // cipher block. This is done to make encryption more secure. 
    // There is also a mode called ECB which does not need an IV,
    // but it is much less secure. 
    alg.Key = Key; 
    alg.IV = IV; 

    // Create a CryptoStream through which we are going to be
    // pumping our data. 
    // CryptoStreamMode.Write means that we are going to be
    // writing data to the stream 
    // and the output will be written in the MemoryStream
    // we have provided. 
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, 
        alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write); 

    // Write the data and make it do the decryption 
    cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length); 

    // Close the crypto stream (or do FlushFinalBlock). 
    // This will tell it that we have done our decryption
    // and there is no more data coming in, 
    // and it is now a good time to remove the padding
    // and finalize the decryption process. 
    cs.Close(); 

    // Now get the decrypted data from the MemoryStream. 
    // Some people make a mistake of using GetBuffer() here,
    // which is not the right way. 
    byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray(); 

    return decryptedData; 
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: This is a bad online tool! It propagates insecure code and doesn't even provide compatible code on the same site for Java and PHP. It's just that bad. If you just want to have a compatible code, use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor)

Comment: *"all online code samples I found gave me gibberish characters"* - Modern encryption algorithms produce binary data, but binary data can be rarely represented by a valid character encoding such as UTF-8 or even ASCII. If you want to print such ciphertext, you need to encode them to Hex or Base64 or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, using

```
        public string AES_DEC(string text, string password)
    {
        RijndaelManaged aes256 = new RijndaelManaged();

        aes256.KeySize = 128;
        aes256.BlockSize = 128;
        aes256.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes256.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aes256.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        aes256.GenerateIV();

        byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        ICryptoTransform transform = aes256.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] plainText = transform.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
    }
```

I still do not know what I was doing wrong